# Bluetooth low energy advertisement scan, channel info or selection

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I've written an application using bluez, which scans for BLE advertisement data. The application currently receives advertisement messages with no problems.

For advertisement messages, BLE sends messages using 3 channels which are 37, 38 and 39. Each uses a different frequency. When the application receives data, I'd like to be able to determine on which channel that data was received. If that is not possible, would it be possible to force a low energy scan on a single channel or a subset of the 3 channels.

Answer (score 1):

In the **le_set_advertising_parameters_cp** structure there is chann_map;

if this bit is set to 1 channel 37 is used, and if bit is set to 2

channel 38 is used ,and if bit is set to 4 channel 39 is used, and if bit

is set to 7 all channels are enabled;more details page 1058 in spec4.0

Comment: What you have written is correct. In the hciconfig.c code, function cmd_le_adv, the above structure is used to set the channels used for advertising data. However my objective is to determine the channel on which advertisement data is received or select the channel on which I wish to receive data. I'm not sure if this is applicable to data reception. I will have a look through the source in a bit more detail.

Comment: Some more info: I use the hci_le_set_scan_parameters and hci_le_set_scan_enable to perform le scans. However so far have not found anything for setting channels or reporting the channel number on which data is received.

Comment: Well on the Rx side I dont think there is such option to choose

Comment: Just a follow up. I use a Nordic semiconductor BLE module as a beacon (nrf51822). Using their API it is possible to set the channel or channels used for advertisement messages. The same is true for bluez. Since I know the channel, I included the channel info in the advertisement packet. In the case where I have complete control of the beacon software, it has proved to be a feasible solution.