# Bluetooth LE set advertising channel - Android

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon-android

When advertising BLE on an Android device, is there some way to set or even just check the advertising channel currently used?

I noticed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866446/bluetooth-low-energy-advertisement-scan-channel-info-or-selection) question concerning Linux, but is there a similar way for android?

If that is not possible is there a BLE beacon brand/model that supports this setting?

Comment: I do not believe there are any Android APIs that expose this ability.  It may be supported by lower level chipsets, but you would probably have to root an Android device to access the hardware directly, and it would be a device specific implementation.

Comment: @davidgyoung thanks for the answer, I almost fear you are right

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get the Advertisement Channel value. It gets set internally by Bluetooth Services and stack.

The value being set up by AdvertiseManager.java class is given below.

```
 private static final int ADVERTISING_CHANNEL_ALL =
                ADVERTISING_CHANNEL_37 | ADVERTISING_CHANNEL_38 | ADVERTISING_CHANNEL_39;
```

You can alos look at  [AdvertiseManager's Implementation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/+/master/src/com/android/bluetooth/gatt/AdvertiseManager.java), check line 252 and 352.

Comment: that is a good hint, thank you.

Do you by any chance know whether or how it is possible to edit that class or implement a substitution? Sorry, it's a bit unknown terrrain for me.

Comment: Its a part of Bluetooth App/Service. Only Manufacturer can make changes in it, or if you are building a custom rom. Not from Application level.

Comment: I see. Well that's not a real option for me.
But thank you again.